# Argument in message expression is an uninitialized value

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, switch-statement

The code works correctly, but I am getting the warning *"Argument in message expression is an initialized value"* for this piece of code:

```
    NSString *quality;
    switch(theItem.quality) {
        case 1:
            quality = @"UNDEF, Set it up!";
            break;
        case 2:
            quality = @"G, (Good)";
            break;
        case 3:
            quality = @"VG, (Very Good)";
            break;
        case 4:
            quality = @"F, (Fine)";
            break;
        case 5:
            quality = @"VF, (Very Fine)";
            break;
        case 6:
            quality = @"XF, (Extra Fine)";
            break;
        case 7:
            quality = @"UNC, (Uncirculated)";
            break;
        case 8:
            quality = @"PROOF, (Proof)";
            break;
    }

    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quality];
```

Is it some issue or it's nothing and I can ignore it?
Also, is it ok to initialize NSString this way -> `NSString *quality;`?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't say 'uninitialized'?

Comment: It is OK to create a pointer with `NSString *quality;` IF you are using ARC. Otherwise set it to nil with `NSString *quality = nil;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean "uninitialized value"? If none of your case statements match, the `quality` variable will end up being uninitialized, which will likely crash once it gets to the `+stringWithFormat:`. You can either initialize `quality` with a default value (perhaps `nil`), or you can provide a `default` statement in your `switch` that initializes it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than:

```
NSString *quality;
```

use:

```
NSString *quality = nil;
```

Even if all values are definitely accounted for in the `switch`, and `quality` will definitely be assigned, that may not be true in the future due to changes (elsewhere) in the codebase. It's best practice to assign a default value, hence the warning.

Adding a `default:` case to your switch statement and assigning a default `quality` value will also fix the warning:

```
case 8:
    quality = @"PROOF, (Proof)";
    break;
default:
    quality = @"UNKNOWN QUALITY";
```